# Aggregating a table by multiple different column filters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that groups a table by a certain column and provides some aggregate data based on some filtering. Currently, the only way I know how to achieve the query is to use a number of subqueries, which seems inefficient. Let's assume I have the following table:

```
user_id  event_type  value
      1       click      4
      2       click      2
      1       click      1
      4       close      5
      2        open      3
```

I want to group the data by `user_id` and aggregate the following information: `max_value`, `min_click_value`. Based on the example table able, this is the result I'd like to see:

```
user_id  max_value  min_click_value
      1          4                1
      2          3                2
      4          5             null
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without subqueries? What I have so far is this, which works, but it feels pretty inefficent:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, max_value, min_click_value
(SELECT user_id, MAX(value) as max_value 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY user_id) as t1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT user_id, MIN(value) as min_click_value 
FROM my_table 
WHERE event_type = "click" 
GROUP BY user_id) as t2
WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select user_id, max(value) as max_value
       min(case when event_type = 'click' then value end) as min_click_value
from my_table
group by user_id;
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Gordon!

Answer (score 3):

Conditional aggregation should work here:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    MAX(value) AS max_value,
    MIN(CASE WHEN event_type = 'click' THEN value END) AS min_click_value
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    user_id;
```